# is there a way adding webex meeting to use google calendar api?

Tags: google-calendar-api, webex

I'm beginner looking for way to make schedule adding webex meeting..
i found google calendar API, but it seems only support hangout / meets..

is anybody know the way to add webex meeting in conference type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have checked the [GSuite Updates blog](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/09/third-party-conferencing-available-google-calendar.html), the third-party conferencing is available in Google Calendar.

> We’re launching with five partners whose add-ons are available in the
>   [G Suite
>   Marketplace](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-calendar),
>   with more to come in the future:
>
> - Cisco (Webex integration)
> - Dialpad (UberConference integration)
> - LogMeIn (GoToMeeting integration)
> - RingCentral (RingCentral integration)
> - Vonage (Vonage integration)

But if you read [the current release notes](https://developers.google.com/calendar/releases/) in the Google Calendar API documentation, it was not yet stated that these partners are live. So I think we have to wait for the update in the documentation.

Comment: Wow! It sounds great!! Thank you for answer my questions!!

Comment: So can we integrate webex with google calendar API?
If yes can please someone guide me through code.